# Android gridview fail to refresh after image is removed

Tags: android, gridview

Below is my code modified from other sample.

Now my flow is user will select multiple images and when click on SELECT button, will have alertdialog pop up to ask "Remove the photo once upload successful"

so when finished upload it will call onActivityResult.

in onActivityResult, I will

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {      
    case UPLOAD_IMAGES:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
            imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imagegrid.invalidateViews();    
            AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this
            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateUI();
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Updated UI");           
        }
    }
}
```

But my gridview still fail to refresh, the removed image still show.

Full source code is here.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imageAdapter.initialize();
    imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this
    .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateUI();
        }
    });

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = imageAdapter.images.size();
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (imageAdapter.images.get(i).selection) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages
                            + imageAdapter.images.get(i).id + ",";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                 selectImages = selectImages.substring(0,selectImages.lastIndexOf(","));
                 AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this);
                 helpBuilder.setTitle("Photo upload");
                 helpBuilder.setMessage("Remove the photo once upload successful.");

                 UploadPhotoOnClickYes uploadPhotoOnClickYes = new UploadPhotoOnClickYes(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this, 
                         UploadQueue.class, selectImages);

                 UploadPhotoOnClickNo uploadPhotoOnClickNo = new UploadPhotoOnClickNo(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this, 
                         UploadQueue.class, selectImages);

                 helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",uploadPhotoOnClickYes);

                 helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", uploadPhotoOnClickNo);

                 // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
                 AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                 helpDialog.show();
                }                                   
            }                       
    });     
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {      
    case UPLOAD_IMAGES:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
            imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imagegrid.invalidateViews();    
            AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this
            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateUI();
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Updated UI");           
        }
    }
}

public void updateUI() {
    imageAdapter.checkForNewImages();
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ArrayList<ImageItem> images = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        images.clear();
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;                 

        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                columns,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
                new String[] {"%DVS%"},                 
                orderBy);
        if(imagecursor != null){
            int image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int count = imagecursor.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                imageItem.id = id;
                lastId = id;
                imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                images.add(imageItem);
            }
            imagecursor.close();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void checkForNewImages(){            
        images.clear(); //new
        //Here we'll only check for newer images
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                columns,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
                new String[] {"%DVS%"},             
                orderBy); //new

        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int count = imagecursor.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
            imageItem.id = id;
            lastId = id;
            imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);             
            images.add(imageItem);
        }
        imagecursor.close();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ImageItem item = images.get(position);
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {               
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (images.get(id).selection) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    images.get(id).selection = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    images.get(id).selection = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                int id = v.getId();
                ImageItem item = images.get(id);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = " + item.id, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0){
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(0);
                    String path = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    File file = new File(path);
                    imagecursor.close();
                    intent.setDataAndType(
                            Uri.fromFile(file),
                            "image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, VIEW_IMAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(item.img);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(item.selection);
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
}

class ImageItem {
    boolean selection;
    int id;
    Bitmap img;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself this is because I delete the image using file.delete. So it only remove the physical file but the removed image still cached.

So need to use this method to remove the file.

```
Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri, item.media_id);
getContentResolver().delete(itemUri, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't try your code right now, but try this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {      
    case UPLOAD_IMAGES:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
            imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this
            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateUI();
                    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Updated UI");           
        }
    }
}
```

I just moved the invalidation of the gridview after you remove the elements.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but the gridview is still not updated.. the removed image is still show..

Comment: Hmm, try this instead of the `imagegrid.invalidateViews()`: `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`